# Audio not working at all after three overheat resets followed by a scan in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, boot, audio, drivers, cpu

So, the audio stopped working completely in my PC, The motherboard is an Asrock H81M-HDS with an i5 4460 quad core processor. Along with 8 GB of DDR3 RAM and a GTX 760. The system suddenly reset after I booted up a game called Black Squad while in a Discord call. After the third time, doing the exact same thing, I decided to take a look in my case.

My heat sink was clogged. So I took care of that and put it back together, plugged everything in and booted the PC up. I went ahead afterwards to scan using Malwarebytes in safe mode. After I restarted, I went out of safe mode and booted as normal, only to discover that I have no sound. I did another scan, looked at my drivers, updated them, restart, no change. Uninstalled and reinstalled, no change. I checked the HD audio cable. Nothing wrong. Headphones are plugged in. They're not recognized.

On my device manager I have: Nivdia HD audio, Nivdia Virtual Audio and Realtek HD Audio for 'devices' installed. Could there be some kind of conflict in the devices? Perhaps it could be one of the anti-virus programs I have, which are Avast, Malwarebytes and CCCleaner. The playback devices show the realtek audio as a device, but it says nothing is plugged in. I've done all I can and I want to avoid going to a shop to get it fixed, as I don't have the money to fork over for service.

Please help me. I would be ever thankful if a solution is found.

Update: I have tried the following:
: Checked playback devices: Nothing
Checked drivers: and updated: Nothing changed
Used Microsoft's sound troubleshooter: 'Plug in headphones'
Tried adding legacy hardware: Nothing new found
Checked BIOS for sound options: Only Auto and Disabled are the options.
Tried using a restore point: Failed to restore.
Tried using disc that came with PC: No change.

Comment: Try a live linux CD or stick - can it operate the soundcard? If yes, the problem is indeed with windows drivers, if no, the hardware is probably fried....

Comment: This^^^ and maybe try the Nvidia audio (HDMI) because it's a different and independent sound card. Everything else you've been doing is illogical. I suspect that sooner or later you will realize the motherboard's sound chip (Realtek) is fried.